# Is a backdoor ROTH IRA contribution still worth it if I have pre-tax IRAs that I can't rollover to a 401k yet?

Tags: ira, roth-ira, contribution, rollover, roth-conversion

Starting this year, I can no longer contribute to my ROTH IRA. I have three other IRAs:

- A rollover IRA (pre-tax), opened in 2020 when I rolled over an old 401k.
- A SIMPLE IRA (pre-tax), opened in 2020 with my old employer.
- A traditional IRA, containing $3k of **post-tax contributions**, uninvested, which I opened last week, intending to put $6k in there and do a backdoor ROTH IRA contribution.

After I opened the traditional IRA and put the $3k, I learned more about the *pro rata* rule. I understand that if I do the backdoor ROTH this year, equal amounts will need to be converted from each of the above IRAs, resulting in my needing to pay some taxes.

Optimally, I'd love to convert the rollover and SIMPLE IRAs into a new 401k which my current company is making available soon. However, I don't think I can do that because of how recently the rollover and SIMPLE IRAs were opened.

I want to get as much money into my ROTH as possible so I can enjoy tax-free growth. I'm only 27 so this is significant.

Given my situation, what's the best course of action here? Should I do *pro rata* conversions every year until I'm able to roll my pre-tax IRAs into my new 401k? I have the money to pay the taxes I need to, if that's the best decision in the long run.

Comment: Where are you seeing there is a constraint on how long you need to have an IRA before reverse rolling it over into your 401(k)?

Comment: Is the traditional IRA contribution for last year, or this year?

Comment: OK, hang on. You actually have a [two-year holding period](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/simple-ira-plan-faqs-distributions) on your SIMPLE IRA from the first contribution. ([Handy chart.](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/rollover_chart.pdf))

Comment: @CraigW I made the 3k traditional IRA contribution for 2021.

Answer (score 3):

There is no time or amount limit for conversions (except processing time between contributions and conversions, so maybe two days inbetween).

You can convert *all your SEP IRAs and Traditional IRAs* today (or any other day) if you want to (but consider the taxes that you will have to pay for it).

This is independant of pre-tax and / or post-tax contributions - post-tax conversions will be tax free; pre-tax conversions are taxable, but they are *always* considered ’merged’ by the IRS, no matter how clear you separate them, so any conversion is always a proportional mix.

Once you merged pre- and post-tax money, it’s merged, until you empty *all* your IRAs past a year change; and you need to keep track with form 8086 (or get double taxed).

Comment: You can't do posttax conversions independently of pretax conversions. Any conversion of balances in traditional IRAs are subject to the pro-rata rule; the amount you convert will be prorated between your posttax and pretax balances in their proportion across all your traditional IRAs. (This is the purpose of Form 8606, which you file each time you contribute or Roth-convert any traditional IRA balance which contains a posttax portion.)

Comment: I am aware of that; I didn’t try to imply different. I’ll adjust the wording.

Comment: @Aganju If I'm understanding you right, you're saying I could literally convert my IRAs to ROTH IRA at any time (except for the the 2-year wait for the SIMPLE IRA). Furthermore, it sounds like there isn't any downside to doing the pro rata conversions other than the need to pay taxes now. Which seems like the way to go, since I'd then get tax-free growth for decades.

Comment: @DavidGay Traditional IRA's also grow tax-free. The only difference between Roth and trad is whether you pay taxes on the way in and on the way out. Well, a non-deductible traditional IRA is certainly strictly worse than a Roth.

Comment: @KevinArlin You bring up a good point, and I've been a bit confused on it. I've read that earnings are taxed when you make a withdrawal, but I've also read that earnings grow tax-free. So I'm not sure what "earnings grow tax-free" means, if your earnings are being taxed.

Comment: @DavidGay It means you don't have to pay capital gains taxes when you sell investments within the account. This is the main advantage of IRA's. In a taxable account, you pay income tax, then invest your money, and pay capital gains every time you sell a winning investment, after which the cash is yours. A Roth IRA is the same on the front end but with no capital gains tax ever; a deductible Trad IRA also has no capital gains ever and moves the income tax to when you withdraw in retirement. On a non-deductible trad IRA, I guess you pay income tax on both ends, hence the backdoor Roth.

Comment: @DavidGay FYI I'm also a young investor, who's also found it really hard to get a precise answer on how all this works (in particular, many authors online don't seem to understand that the two kinds of IRA are totally equivalent unless your income tax rates are different in retirement than during the career,) so this is my current understanding but I may be wrong about something.

Comment: @KevinArlin no, even with identical tax rates they are not identical - Roth has the advantage that all gains are tax free; IRA gains are taxed when you take them out.

Comment: Agreed with Aganju. I find it helpful to distinguish contributions and gains. Traditional IRA contributions are deducted when you contribute them, but contributions and gains are taxed at *income tax rates* when you withdraw/convert. Nondeductible IRA contributions aren't deducted when you contribute them and aren't taxed when you withdraw them, but gains are taxed at *income tax rates* when you withdraw/convert. For stock investments in your brokerage account, gains are taxed at the *lower long-term capital gains tax rates* when you sell.

Comment: And Roth IRA contributions aren't deducted when you contribute them, and aren't taxed when you withdraw them, and the gains are never taxed.

Comment: @Aganju No, "gains are tax-free" is not an advantage of Roth over traditional. Just multiply the numbers. If I deposit 100K in a Roth IRA and pay 20% tax, I let 80K grow, maybe to 800K (a factor of 10) at retirement. If I deposit 100K in a deductible traditional IRA then I pay no tax, let it grow to 1M, and then pay 20% tax on withdrawing to end up with 800K.

Comment: @user106227 Adding on the nondeductible IRA situation, I save 100K of before-tax income, pay 20K in tax, let 80K grow to 800K, then withdraw it, you're saying I only pay tax on the 700K in gains? That's an interesting detail though AFAICT there's no reason to ever do this rather than a backdoor Roth. It also seems that there would almost never be an advantage to using a taxable brokerage account over an IRA, even if the capital gains rate is below the income rate, since you still have to pay the income rate on the contributions. So I think all of that is beside the most important point here.

Comment: @KevinArlin re. your reply to Aganju -- not precisely. Let's say your AGI is 50k and your average tax rate is 20%. You can pay 10k in tax this year, contribute 6k to a Roth this year, and let it grow to 60k for a net gain of 60k-6k-10k=44k. Or, you can pay (50k-6k)*20%=8.8k in tax this year, contribute 6k to a traditional this year, it grows to 60k, and you pay 60k*20%=12k in tax on withdrawal for a net gain of 60k-6k-8.8k-12k=33.2k. The point is that your traditional contribution is *pretax* dollars, so it doesn't go as far as an equal amount in Roth *posttax* dollars.

Comment: In other words, you need to account for the fact that you have the same contribution limit  per year for traditional pretax dollars as for Roth posttax dollars, so you should prefer Roth if your tax rate is constant. (Numbers above were chosen to be within the limit for traditional IRA deduction eligibility.)

Comment: @KevinArlin re your reply to me. I agree with you on your analysis of nondeductible contributions. The brokerage account is still potentially beneficial over a traditional IRA (but definitely worse than a Roth): if your AGI is 50k, you pay 10k in tax, invest 6k, let it grow to 60k, realise capital gain of 54k, pay a LT capital gains tax rate of (say) 15%<20% so 8.1k, net gain is 60k-6k-10k-8.1k=35.9k which slightly beats out the traditional IRA. (The other benefit of a brokerage account is that there is no contribution limit of 6k!)

Comment: Then why is a traditional IRA useful? (1) You'll notice my calculations are combining cash flows from different times: before and after the capital gain occurred. This isn't valid because of the time value of money. Many people want to take the tax deduction to pay less in taxes now. (2) I've assumed throughout that tax rate is constant at 20%, which is patently untrue. If you reckon your tax rate will decrease, you should contribute to a traditional and withdraw/convert when your tax rate decreases. It's a way to smooth income over your lifetime.

Comment: @user106227 Ahhh, thanks very much! That's a great point about 6000 post-tax dollars being way more than 6000 pre-tax dollars. I find that calculation quite surprising and I wish I would've seen it on any number of online discussions of this issue.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I would keep the money in your traditional IRA and look into rolling your other IRAs into your current 401(k). Once you get that done, then you can freely convert your Traditional IRA, and only pay tax on the gains. As Aganju mentioned in their answer (which this is somewhat an extension of), there is no time limit on conversions. So you could leave this money in your traditional IRA for several years until it is advantageous to do the conversion, if necessary. If you really want to minimize your taxes, you could even roll over the earnings in your traditional IRA as well, and only leave the non-deductible basis, so there would be zero tax on the conversion.

If there is really no chance you'll be able to get your other IRA money into a 401(k), then you should do a withdrawal of excess contributions with your brokerage. But there is no rush because you have until you file your 2021 taxes, which should be at least a year away.

Comment: This is useful info. So (1) I can roll over my pre-tax IRAs into my 401k and leave the post-tax traditional IRA behind, and (2) I can safely invest my money in the traditional IRA, and just pay tax on the gains when I eventually roll it into my ROTH. Is that correct? The one thing I don't follow on is the withdrawal of excess contributions you mention. Though it's true I can't roll over my SIMPLE in 2021, I only plan to put the $6,000 limit into my IRA this year. What would cause me to need to withdraw excess contributions?

Comment: @DavidGay Yes both (1) and (2) are correct. The only reasons you'd want to withdraw your contributions is if your 401(k) doesn't accept incoming rollovers, or for some reason you don't want to roll over the money, e.g. your 401(k)'s fees are too high. In those cases I'd advise withdrawing the money rather than leaving it in non-deductible traditional IRA status indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'd suggest you [withdraw](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a#en_US_2020_publink1000230703) your $3k after-tax contribution. You can do this by 15 October with an extension or amended return. You'd pay tax on the gains, which should be minimal since you didn't invest the $3k.</strike>

Then, you can do a combination of the following to get to a zero balance on your pretax IRA:

- convert your pretax IRAs to Roth to pay taxes now and get tax-free growth
- if your 401(k) accepts rollovers from IRAs, reverse rollover your pretax IRAs to your traditional 401(k) to pay no taxes now

Finally, make a new $6k posttax contribution. This, you must do by 15 April; extensions aren't allowed.

Aganju points out that the sequence of events is immaterial. And in any case, what I'd said was incorrect; any conversion or rollover you do in calendar 2021 can only show up in your 2021 tax return. So it looks like the only thing you can do to not trigger the pro-rata rule is to skip your 2020 contribution.

You'll have to either:

- live with it and file Form 8606 each year you contribute or Roth-convert posttax balances, or
- withdraw the 2020 contribution you've made and not make any posttax contributions without first clearing out the entire IRA's balance using a reverse 401(k) rollover / Roth conversion (and for the SIMPLE IRA, you'd [have to wait two years from your first contribution](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/simple-ira-plan-faqs-distributions)).

Comment: This would be useless and unnecessary- all activity within the calendar year is consider one activity, the sequence doesn't matter, and there is no need anyway.

Comment: @Aganju Good point about the sequence not mattering; I edited my answer.

Comment: From the other answers, it sounds like I can still make my 2021 contribution to a traditional IRA, but can wait to convert it to ROTH until 2022, after I've rolled over my other IRAs into a 401k. That way I'd avoid the pro rata rule.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. My answer was incorrectly assuming that your 3k contribution was for 2020, but it sounds like you made the contribution for 2021, so what I said doesn't apply to you.